# Facebox in asp.net - update database, using preset textbox values in the facebox

Tags: asp.net, textbox, facebox

I've been using Facebox lately, and it seems like it doesn't play well with asp.net. With the help from this forum, i solved the problems with retrieving values from textboxes, as well as capturing the event from a button inside the facebox.

Now, I have stumbled onto another strange problem. If i populate the textboxes inside the facebox with existing values, before the facebox is opened, open the facebox, change some of the values, hit a button that graps the new values from the textboxes, the values that are grapped are the ones the textboxes were populated with before the facebox was opened.

This is the code in my .aspx page:

```
<a href="#facebox" rel="facebox">open facebox</a>
    <div id="facebox" style="display: none;">
        <p>
            1:&nbsp;<span><asp:TextBox ID="txt_reason1" runat="server" Width="200" TextMode="MultiLine"
                Rows="2"></asp:TextBox></span></p>
        <p>
            2:&nbsp;<span><asp:TextBox ID="txt_reason2" runat="server" Width="200" TextMode="MultiLine"
                Rows="2"></asp:TextBox></span></p>
        <p>
            3:&nbsp;<span><asp:TextBox ID="txt_reason3" runat="server" Width="200" TextMode="MultiLine"
                Rows="2"></asp:TextBox></span></p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Gem" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    </div>
```

Then in my codebehind, I set the textboxes (when the page loads) in the facebox like this: (_goal is a business object)

```
    txt_reason1.Text = _goal.GoalReason1;
    txt_reason2.Text = _goal.GoalReason2;
    txt_reason3.Text = _goal.GoalReason3;
```

I then change some values in the .aspx and hit the button with this code in the eventhandler:

```
    _goal.GoalReason1 = txt_reason1.Text;
    _goal.GoalReason2 = txt_reason2.Text;
    _goal.GoalReason3 = txt_reason3.Text;
    bool res = GoalManager.UpdateGoal(_goal);
```

which pretty much just sets some object properties with the textbox values, and updates the database with it. But, the textbox values are not changed, and I checked it using the debugger. My guess is that facebox is somehow denying the textboxes to be changed. I don't know, so I was hoping that someone in here knows more about facebox, and maybe even solved this problem...

Comment: Are you using AJAX to do callbacks? Or traditional postbacks? This could have an effect on the facebox script's initialization which 'could' be causing issues...

Comment: Hey, I'm using traditional postbacks. Just a simple button Click event.

Comment: It seems that facebox, when it loads, creates its own containing DIV with an id=facebox. 
So, even I give my facebox DIV an id=facebox2, the one that the user sees in the browser has an id=facebox. So, if the user changes the content of the textboxes, the values that are submitted are not the new ones. Confusing....
Maybe I could let the submit button call some javascript that graps the newly entered values from the facebox "DIV-copy", and calls a pagemethod with those values as parameters, instead of letting the button do a direct postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find a solution in this thread. Closed....